# How to handle different Events from different Controls in one method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView SelectionChanged event and a DatePicker SelectedDateChanged event, both named "Changes".

```
    private void Changes(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Process selected Items from ListView an Date from DatePicker
    }
```

So both events are handled using the same method, which is exactly what I want. However, if I try the same thing with a TextBox SelectionChanged event, Visual Studio creates a new event handler (probably because of the different types of the e argument?). Is it possible to call my Changes method when I write text in the TextBox?

Comment: Why not have multiple event handlers that all call another method? Otherwise just use `EventArgs e`.

Comment: Since this is WPF, you should probably be using viewmodel bindings instead of handling events.

Comment: @Clemens :I load txt files and display them in a datagrid. The other controls serve as filters for the list. So I figured it would be easy to just implement all the filters in one method.

Comment: That does not mean different event handler could not all call the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any of methods as any event handler, via lambda expression:

```
listView1.SelectionChanged += Changes;
datePicker1.SelectedDateChanged += Changes;
textBox1.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => Changes(sender, null);
```

If you are using `SelectionChangedEventArgs` inside of method, you will need to create it manually with needed data inside which may be harder than creating multiple handlers.

Comment: Careful with lambda-registered events - how do you de-register them later and avoid a memory leak?